Creation Of An Object-Based State Causing useEffect To Trigger On Mount
I am establishing a state like so:
 const today = new Date();
const year = today.getFullYear();
const month = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
const day = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
const formattedDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
const [selectedDateRange, setSelectedDateRange] = useState({startDay: formattedDate, endDay:formattedDate});

And if that selectedDateRange were to change, I want a useEffect to detect that and refetch relevant data like so:
  useEffect(()=>{
  fetchPerformanceData();
}, [selectedDateRange])

However, I am noticing that every time I refresh the page, or some sort of re-render triggers, that the useEffect above is being triggered (and I obviously have no idea why). Any insight would be extraordinarily helpful!

I am noticing that every time I refresh the page On refresh sounds normal. The first render always runs effects. As for the rerender case, either selectedDateRange must have changed, or the component must have unmounted/remounted. You can check if it is unmounting with:  useEffect(() => () => console.log('unmount!'), [])

Using objects or arrays in the dependency leads to this. You can make it compare the values of selectedDateRange using stringify or by listing the actual fields from the date range that would necessitate this effect run.
useEffect(()=>{
  fetchPerformanceData();
}, [JSON.stringify(selectedDateRange)])

or
useEffect(()=>{
  fetchPerformanceData();
}, [selectedDateRange.startDay, selectedDateRange.endDay])


Interesting, so I have tried both of the options above, but both have still lead to useEffect triggering.

Is the component unmounting/remounting? You can find out with useEffect(() => () => console.log('unmount!'), [])

So long as objects and arrays are stable references it doesn't matter much if they are used as dependencies. In fact you can depend on React state being a stable reference that only changes when you enqueue an update. Of course this all assumes you correctly update state and don't mutate it elsewhere.
